# Dear pygui поддержка кириллицы

Tags: python, gui, dearpygui

Подскажите, пожалуйста, поддерживает ли [DearPyGui](https://github.com/hoffstadt/DearPyGui) кириллицу? Может кто-то сталкивался.

Comment: А почему вы не проверите самостоятельно? Устанавливаете его, берете пример из спеки https://github.com/hoffstadt/DearPyGui#usage, вместо `core.add_text("Hello world")` пишите `core.add_text("Привет мир")` и запускаете

Comment: Проверил, выводит знаки вопроса. Вот меня интересует может кто-то решил эту проблему

Comment: Такое нужно в вопросе показывать с кодом и скриншотом :) Скорее всего, нужно поменять шрифт в этой библиотеке на тот, что кириллицу поддерживает

Comment: https://github.com/hoffstadt/DearPyGui_06/wiki/Fonts и https://github.com/hoffstadt/DearPyGui/issues/209

Comment: Спасибо. Добавил add_additional_font(file = "noto-mono.regular.ttf", size = 14, glyph_ranges   = 'cyrillic')

Comment: Все заработало))

Comment: Вы молодец :) Оформите, пожалуйста, сами ответ, я вам плюс поставлю ;) Внизу должна быть кнопка вида "ответить на собственный вопрос"

Answer (score 2):

Сработало добавление:

```
add_additional_font(file = "noto-mono.regular.ttf", size = 14, glyph_ranges = 'cyrillic')
```

Answer (score 0):

В стандарном шрифте нет русских символов, нужно скачать новый шрифт с поддержкой кириллицы и установить его как дефолтный:

```
with dpg.font_registry():
    with dpg.font("notomono-regular.ttf", 13, default_font=True, tag="Default font") as f:
        dpg.add_font_range_hint(dpg.mvFontRangeHint_Cyrillic)
    
dpg.bind_font("Default font")
```

Тем не менее, нельзя будет вводить в input кириллицей, буквы не будут корректно отображаться.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
import dearpygui.dearpygui as dpg

dpg.create_context()

**big_let_start = 0x00C0  # Capital "A" in cyrillic alphabet
big_let_end = 0x00DF  # Capital "Я" in cyrillic alphabet
small_let_end = 0x00FF  # small "я" in cyrillic alphabet
remap_big_let = 0x0410  # Starting number for remapped cyrillic alphabet
alph_len = big_let_end - big_let_start + 1  # adds the shift from big letters to small
alph_shift = remap_big_let - big_let_start  # adds the shift from remapped to non-remapped
with dpg.font_registry():
    with dpg.font("fonts/Akrobat-SemiBold.otf", 18) as default_font:
        dpg.add_font_range_hint(dpg.mvFontRangeHint_Default)
        dpg.add_font_range_hint(dpg.mvFontRangeHint_Cyrillic)
        biglet = remap_big_let  # Starting number for remapped cyrillic alphabet
        for i1 in range(big_let_start, big_let_end + 1):  # Cycle through big letters in cyrillic alphabet
            dpg.add_char_remap(i1, biglet)  # Remap the big cyrillic letter
            dpg.add_char_remap(i1 + alph_len, biglet + alph_len)  # Remap the small cyrillic letter
            biglet += 1  # choose next letter
        dpg.bind_font(default_font)**

dpg.create_viewport(title='Основное окно программы', width=800, height=600)
dpg.setup_dearpygui()

with dpg.window(label="Еще одно окно"):
    dpg.add_text("Просто текст")
    dpg.add_button(label="Сохранить")
    dpg.add_input_text(label="строка")
    dpg.add_slider_float(label="число с плавающей точкой")

dpg.show_viewport()
dpg.start_dearpygui()
dpg.destroy_context()
```

= = =

Шрифты качал отсюда:
https://fontstorage.com/ru/category/

Незабываем шрифт кинуть в папку, которая указана тут:
with dpg.font("fonts/Akrobat-SemiBold.otf", 18) as default_font:

Для русского языка достаточно выделенного жирным кода.