# Невозможно применить кириллический ввод текста dearpygui

Tags: python, gui, dearpygui

Я пытался использовать вариант решения проблемы используя:

```
with dpg.font_registry():
    with dpg.font(f'fonts\\TNR.ttf', 16, default_font=True, id="Default font", tag="Default font"):
        dpg.add_font_range_hint(dpg.mvFontRangeHint_Cyrillic)
dpg.bind_font("Default font")
```

Но вместо исправления поля ввода, на русском корректно стало отображаться только название окна и текст

[image: таки вот так это выглядит]

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Видя такой гемор с кириллицей в dearpygui каждый раз хочется посоветовать использовать любую другую GUI библиотеку.

Answer (score 0):

Подобный вопрос уже [задавался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1283316/dear-pygui-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b).

Код из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1528937/465999):

```
...
big_let_start = 0x00C0  # Capital "A" in cyrillic alphabet
big_let_end = 0x00DF  # Capital "Я" in cyrillic alphabet
small_let_end = 0x00FF  # small "я" in cyrillic alphabet
remap_big_let = 0x0410  # Starting number for remapped cyrillic alphabet
alph_len = big_let_end - big_let_start + 1  # adds the shift from big letters to small
alph_shift = remap_big_let - big_let_start  # adds the shift from remapped to non-remapped
with dpg.font_registry():
    with dpg.font("arial.ttf", 20) as default_font:
        dpg.add_font_range_hint(dpg.mvFontRangeHint_Default)
        dpg.add_font_range_hint(dpg.mvFontRangeHint_Cyrillic)
        biglet = remap_big_let  # Starting number for remapped cyrillic alphabet
        for i1 in range(big_let_start, big_let_end + 1):  # Cycle through big letters in cyrillic alphabet
            dpg.add_char_remap(i1, biglet)  # Remap the big cyrillic letter
            dpg.add_char_remap(i1 + alph_len, biglet + alph_len)  # Remap the small cyrillic letter
            biglet += 1  # choose next letter
        dpg.bind_font(default_font)
...
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]